# Nested classes: Access to protected member of enclosing class from a nested protected class

Tags: c++

This code compiles on msvc/g++:

```
class A{
protected:
    int i;
    class B{
    public:
        A* a;
        B(A* a_)
        :a(a_){
        }
        void doSomething(){
            if (a)
                a->i = 0;//<---- this part
        }       
    };
public:
    A()
    :i(0){
    }
};
```

As you can see, B gets access to "protected" section of enclosing class, although it isn't declared as friend.

Is this a standard(standard-conforming) behavior?

I use this feature sometimes, but I don't remember a rule saying that nested protected class should automatically get access to all protected data of enclosing class.

Comment: Dupe question. I'm not going to search for the original now, though. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the C++03 standard, 11.8p1 says:

> *The members of a nested class have no special access to members of an enclosing class.*

However, the resolution for [defect report 45](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45) (to the standard) states the opposite, and hence defines the behavior you see:

> *A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member.*

In C++0x the text of 11.8 has been changed to reflect this fact, so this is valid behavior for both C++03 and C++0x conforming compilers.

See also [this thread](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/110207-can-nested-class-access-parent-classs-private-member.html) from the [cprogramming.com](http://cprogramming.com) forums.

Comment: +1 Good answer. However, if you google this, there is some IBM XL compiler documentation that only mentions the first part you've stated and implies that the OP's code would not compile. So the portable thing to do currently, until C++0x is widely implemented, would be to declare the nested class as a friend within the enclosing class.

Comment: Good find. A link would be nice for the sake of completeness. :)

Comment: I was being lazy earlier :-), here's the link. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.aix.doc/language_ref/cplr061.html

Comment: @Praetorian I would be included to declare the nested class as a friend because it better describes how I intend the code to behave, so I gave your comment +1 too

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a copy of C++03 handy but from a draft (n3090) of C++0x:

> **11.8 Nested classes**
>
> **1** A nested class
>   is a member and as such has the same
>   access rights as any other member. The
>   members of an enclosing class have no
>   special access to members of a nested
>   class; the usual access rules (Clause
>   11) shall be obeyed.
>
> [ Example:

```
class E {
    int x;
    class B { };
    class I {
        B b; // OK: E::I can access E::B
        int y;
        void f(E* p, int i) {
            p->x = i; // OK: E::I can access E::x
        }
    };
    int g(I* p) {
        return p->y; // error: I::y is private
    }
};
```

So at least in the next standard, enclosed classes can access the outer class' members as any normal member function would.

Update: **This isn't allowed in the current standard. But a defect report ([DR 45](http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45)) was filed to fix this.** *(SigTerm's edit took this one out. Please, be careful.)*

Update #2: I tried with VS2010, g++ (4.0.1 Apple) with `-Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=c++98` and Comeau (4.3.10.1) in strict C++03 mode with C++0x extensions disabled -- all of them seem to accept access to the outer class `private` members in the inner class members.

Answer (score 0):

Refer $9.7/1.

"The nested class is in the scope of its enclosing class. Except by using explicit pointers, references, and object names, declarations in a nested class can use only
type names, static members, and enumerators from the enclosing class."

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a standard(standard-conforming) behavior?

**No**.

According to C++-2003

`Section 11.8.1`

> **Nested classes**
>
> The members of a nested class have no special access to members of an enclosing class, nor to classes or functions  that  have  granted  friendship  to  an  enclosing  class;  the  usual  access  rules  (clause  11)  shall  be obeyed.  The members of an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (clause 11) shall be obeyed.

```
[Example:
class E {
   
    int x;
    class B { };
    class I {
       
       B b;  //error: E::B is private
       int y;
       void f(E* p, int i)
       {
             p->x = i;           //error: E::x is private
       }
    };
    int g(I* p)
    {
           return p->y;  //error: I::y is private
    }
};
—end example]
```

But there is a slight modification to that section in `ISO/IEC N 3092` which says

> **A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member**.  The members of an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (Clause 11) shall be obeyed.