# Is there any difference between a public nested class and a regular class?

Tags: c++, nested-class

Let's say I have:

```
class A {

public:
    class B {

    };

};
```

Is there any difference between that public nested class and just a regular B class which is defined in its own cpp file, except for the fact that A::B must be used in the first option?

Comment: While not really an answer, I recommend not nesting classes in any language that supports it. That tends to add complexity. Even in the cases where it really helps simplifying code, I find that pulling it out to a "real" top-level class actually helps code reuse in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is essentially no difference, except that `A::B` is a member of `A`, and so has all the access rights to private members of `A` that any other member would have.

Comment: Hi.. i've created a public nested B class and i can't see how it accesses the private variables of A.. i guess i don't know the syntax..?

Comment: @rob: It needs an object of type A. It can then access it's members.

Comment: There is no special syntax. `B` is a member of `A`, so it can access an `A` instance's private variables and `A`'s private static functions.

Comment: I don't know if this was tightened or loosened in the last update of the standard. Can you quote the standard and the version because the wording of this did change.

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537969/nested-classes-access-to-protected-member-of-enclosing-class-from-a-nested-prote/3537998#3537998

Comment: [It's only correct for >=C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6998430/3744681)

Answer (score -1):

There isn't any difference other than the scoping rules for "B". Clients that use "B" must qualify its scope with "A::". Nesting the "B" can sometimes be problematic when you want to forward reference it, since C++ compilers typically do not allow you to forward reference a class within a class (it does allow you to forward reference a class within a namespace though).