# How to do visible nested-class for container-class in inheritance level?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, inner-classes

I have some template class

```cpp
template <typename T> class Base { };
```

I trying to inherit **Derived** class from **Base** and use **Internal** class that is nested of **Derived** as a generic argument of **Base**.

```cpp
class Derived : Base<Internal> {
public: class Internal { };
}
```

But compiler doesn't see **Internal** in **Base**.

Is it possible to solve my problem with keeping **Internal** class as nested of **Derived**?
And if it is possible - How?

Comment: I have concerns whether this can work at all but you have to use a scope: `Derived::Internal`.

Comment: @Scheff I tried this one variant too and had the same result, Internal still invisible.

Comment: I doubt that a nested class can be used. A forward declaration isn't an option as well. Maybe something more convoluted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## <s>You can!</s> Nope

([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51548938/1116364))

I don't think that this can work.  In order to *define* the class `Derived` you need to know the base class ("it must be a complete type") first; to instantiate the *template* `Base` into a class you need to have a type.  `Inner` however is only a type "inside" of `Derived`; it's part of it's definition.

```
Definition of Derived  ---needs---> Base<Derived::Inner>
          ^                               |
          |----------needs----------------|
```

Even an indirection does not help:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Base {};

template<template<class> class X, typename T>
struct UseInner : public X<typename T::Inner> {};

class Derived : UseInner<Base, Derived>
{
    public: class Inner {};
};
```

In contrast to this, the CRTP works because there the template parameter can be an *incomplete* type ("no need to access internals").

Wrapping in a template doesn't work:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Base {};

template<template<class>class X>
struct Wrap
{
    struct Derived : X<typename Derived::Inner> {
        struct Inner {};
    };
};

using RealDerived = typename Wrap<Base>::Derived;
```