# C++: Strange "is private" error

Tags: c++, class, private, compiler-bug, g++4.8

I've been getting a very unusual error from g++ claiming that a type alias is private. After hours of reducing my code, I've arrived at the following minimal test case:

```
template <typename Dummy>
class Test {
    struct CatDog {
        static void meow ()
        {
            CrazyHouse::TheCatDog::meow();
        }

        struct Dog {
            static void bark ();
        };
    };

    struct CrazyHouse {
        using TheCatDog = CatDog;

        static void startMadness ()
        {
            TheCatDog::meow();
            TheCatDog::Dog::bark();
        }
    };

public:
    static void init ()
    {
        CrazyHouse::startMadness();
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Test<void> t;
    t.init();
}
```

The error with g++ 4.8.2 is:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'static void Test<Dummy>::CatDog::meow() [with Dummy = void]':
test.cpp:19:29:   required from 'static void Test<Dummy>::CrazyHouse::startMadness() [with Dummy = void]'
test.cpp:27:34:   required from 'static void Test<Dummy>::init() [with Dummy = void]'
test.cpp:34:12:   required from here
test.cpp:15:33: error: 'using TheCatDog = struct Test<void>::CatDog' is private
         using TheCatDog = CatDog;
                                 ^
test.cpp:6:41: error: within this context
             CrazyHouse::TheCatDog::meow();
                                         ^
```

Clang 3.4 accepts the same code. What's going on here, is this a g++ bug?

Doing any of the following stops the error from occuring:

- Turning `Test` into a class, as opposed to a template class.
- Removing any of the statements in any of the functions.
- Changing `TheCatDog::Dog::bark();` to `CatDog::Dog::bark();`.
- Removing the `CrazyHouse` class and merging its contents in `Test`.
- Removing the `CatDog` class, merging its contents into `Test` and changing the `TheCatDog` alias to point to `Test`.

Answer (score 5):

Name lookup on the identifier `CatDog` finds `Test::CatDog` which is declared `private`. The access is performed from `CrazyHouse`, which is not a `friend` of `Test`. Therefore it's an illegal access to a protected member.

As @sj0h notes, in C++11 your example becomes valid because they decided to extend access to the bodies of nested classes in the same way as member functions.

C++98:

> The members of a nested class have no special access to members of an enclosing class, nor to classes or functions that have granted friendship to an enclosing class; the usual access rules (clause 11) shall be obeyed.

C++11:

> A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member.

(Members have the right to access `private` members of the enclosing class.)

However, this change does not appear to be implemented in GCC even in a recent build of version 4.9. So, to be safe, it can't hurt to add a `friend` declaration. This must go *after* the definition of the member:

```
friend struct CrazyHouse;
```

Note that this doesn't accomplish exactly the same thing as the C++11 change, because `friend`ship is not transitive whereas access granted by nested membership is.

Answer (score -1):

The behavior of the compilers can be considered wrong or right depending on which version of C++ we are talking about. It appears that the behavior of clang is correct if we are talking about C++11 and incorrect if we are talking about C++98.

The stackoverflow item [C++ nested class access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998369/c-nested-classes-accessibility) should clarify that.

Comment: I believe you are wrong here, a nested class should have access to private members of the class it is nested in. Example: http://ideone.com/wFeE37

Comment: This accessibility appears to have changed between C++03 and C++11. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998369/c-nested-classes-accessibility

Comment: @sj0h thanks for the link. That explains the difference in behavior.