# Access to protected base enclosing class from derived nested class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, boost, inner-classes

From various sources ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537969/nested-classes-access-to-protected-member-of-enclosing-class-from-a-nested-prot), for example) I'm aware nested classes should be able to see all members of enclosing class, according to C++11 standard.

Nonetheless, I came across the following class hierarchy which DOES NOT compile with Clang.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BaseEnclosing
{
  public :
    BaseEnclosing(double bar) { m_parameters.push_back(bar); }
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
    virtual ~BaseEnclosing() {}

  protected :
    std::vector<double> m_parameters;

    template<class T>
    class BaseNested
    {
      public :
        BaseNested(BaseEnclosing * baseEncPtr) : m_baseEncPtr(baseEncPtr) {}
        virtual void operator()(T param) const = 0;

        virtual ~BaseNested() {}

      protected:
        BaseEnclosing * m_baseEncPtr;
    };
};

class DerivedEnclosing : public BaseEnclosing
{
  public :
    DerivedEnclosing(double bar) : BaseEnclosing(bar) {}
    void DoSomething()
    {
      // call some library functions which use the functor of DerivedNested and pass DerivedNested(this)
    }
    virtual ~DerivedEnclosing() {}

  protected :
    class DerivedNested : public BaseNested<std::vector<double>>
    {
      public :
        DerivedNested(BaseEnclosing * baseEncPtr) : BaseNested(baseEncPtr) {}

        void operator()(std::vector<double> myContainer) const override
        {
          //error: 'm_parameters' is a protected member of 'BaseEnclosing'
          //can only access this member on an object of type 'DerivedEnclosing'
          double retrieved_bar = m_baseEncPtr->m_parameters.back(); //              <---------- ERROR

          // do something with myContainer and retrieved_bar
        }

        virtual ~DerivedNested() {}
      };
};

int main()
{
  DerivedEnclosing test (42.5);
  test.DoSomething();

  return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, `DerivedEnclosing` should inherit `m_parameters` and thus I would expect `DerivedNested`'s methods to see it.

To better understand my intent, I'm trying to use Boost Odeint, which requires a right hand side of the equation specified as either function pointer of functor. I decided to go with the second option in `DoSomething()`.

My design needs `BaseEnclosing` and `DerivedEnclosing` for other purposes, the nested classes are not exactly needed but sounded like a good way to go.

Comment: I was checking out the same answer right now, I believe this clarify my doubt. Thanks!